# Como passar parametro de um Controller para outro em Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Olá, tenho um objeto que preciso passar por parâmetro para um outro Controller através do `RedirectToAction`, usei o `TempData` porém apos qualquer mudança de página ele perde a referência, sabem de alguma solução para que ele não perca a referência? Ou precfisa ser feito de outra forma mesmo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É de outra forma:

```
return RedirectToAction("OutraAction", "Controller", new { minhaClasse = /* objeto do tipo MinhaClasse */, area = "area"})
```

Aí seu `Controller` fica assim:

```
public ActionResult OutraAction(MinhaClasse minhaClasse) { ... }
```

Comment: O RedirectToAction Aceita um outro parâmetro? Eu preciso por um controller de outra área neste RedirectToAction que esqueci de mensionar.

Comment: @LuizNegrini Atualizei.

Comment: Perfeito! Brigadão again!

Comment: @LuizNegrini Deu certo? Poderia aceitar a resposta, em benefício da comunidade?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Cara, não sei porque mas para mim não funcionou. Está tudo certinho, action, parametros e etc... quando faço a requisição ele manda um `SiteTeste.Models.Checkout.CheckoutResultModel` que é o nome do meu objeto que estou passando como uma string, estranho não ? Ai quando eu recebo o parametro na Action cria uma exception null, sera que caiu em desuso ? uso ASP.NET MVC5

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti Tem uma assinatura de método que precisa passar `htmlAttributes` como `null` para funcionar. Tente esta.